# Unity GameObject being deleted after using DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, game-development

I am trying to preserve my character during scene changes using `DontDestroyOnLoad()`, but the character is being destroyed between the menu scene and the actual game even thought I have said `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)`.

[Here is a picture of the Hierarchy and the Game Manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqJMA.png)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public static GameManager instance;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] characters;

    private int _charIndex;
    public int CharIndex
    {
        get{ return _charIndex; }
        set{ _charIndex = value; }
    }

    void Awake(){
    //For the GameManager
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    
    //For the Characters
    for(int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++){
        DontDestroyOnLoad(characters[i]);
    }
}

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnLevelFinishedLoading;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnLevelFinishedLoading;
    }


    void OnLevelFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        if (scene.name == "Gameplay")
        {
            Instantiate(characters[CharIndex]);
        }
    }
} // class
```

I have tried

```
    void Awake(){
    //For the GameManager
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    
    //For the Characters
    for(int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++){
        DontDestroyOnLoad(characters[i]);
    }
```

Instead of

```
if (instance == null)
   {
       instance =this;
       DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
   }
else{
     Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

With the first one, the `Gameplay` wouldn't load and with the second one the scene would load but the characters get destroyed on load.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

I completely missed this and assumed it was an issue with running `DontDestroyOnLoad`, but your problem is that calling [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) clones the object, so when you call `DontDestroyOnLoad` for your characters, you are calling it on Prefab Gameobjects which are not in the scene.

##### Solution:

1. Create an array for your instantiated GameObjects with the length of the original characters array and is populated by the instantiated objects
2. Call `DontDestroyOnLoad()` on THESE objects

```
private GameObject[] instantiatedCharacters;

...

void Awake(){
    //For the GameManager
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    
    //Create array with correct length. This is not strictly necessary, but will be needed if you want to destroy the objects from here.
    //This might need to go in Start()
    instantiatedCharacters = new GameObject[characters.length];
}

...


void OnLevelFinishedLoading(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode){
    if (scene.name == "Gameplay"){
        //
        instantiatedCharacters[CharIndex] = Instantiate(characters[CharIndex]);

        //Dont Destroy the newly created objects
        DontDestroyOnLoad(instantiatedCharacters[CharIndex]);
    }
}
```

##### Original Answer:

Instance is uninitialized and will always be null on load. You need `instance = this;` outside of the if statement in Awake()

Each time Awake() executes, you are calling `Destroy(gameObject);`

Edit:
Because the picture shows that the `GameManager` class is on a separate objects and you are trying to preserve the characters, you need to call `DontDestroyOnLoad` for each one.

```
void Awake(){
    //For the GameManager
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    
    //For the Characters
    for(int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
        DontDestroyOnLoad(characters[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I positioned `instance = this;` before the if statement in `Awake()`.But it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @EmileYoussefFEGHALIEL If you remove the if statement and have only `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)`, the gameObject that this script is attached to wont be destroyed. If you also want the characters in `characters` to be preserved you will need to do `DontDestroyOnLoad(characters[i])` for each one.

Comment: I have removed the if statement, but I am still having some trouble.                                 `   private void Awake()
    {   
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
`

Comment: @EmileYoussefFEGHALIEL That will keep objects which have the `GameManager` script loaded. What is happening now?

Comment: For now nothing has changed. The player still don't appear.

Comment: @EmileYoussefFEGHALIEL That is a link to a local path on your computer.

Comment: Sorry, by mistake.

Comment: Is `GameManager` attached to the player?

Comment: No, I did not. But I have put the players in the characters list

Comment: Yo, did you use the link I gave you ? If yes you might want to be carefull. My computer has been acting strangely lately. I still have not done a virus scan.

Comment: @EmileYoussefFEGHALIEL take a look at the updated answer.  I found a problem that I missed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

DontDestroyOnLoad only works for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects. You are trying to not destroy an array of gameobjects which I am not sure can be done unless you have the gameobjects in the Hierarchy as a root object and the gamemanager script attached to it.